# VBA PowerPoint Mouseout Technique Not Called

Tags: vba, powerpoint, mouseout

I believe I have a problem with powerpoint macros that is keeping me from getting my desired behavior. I'm attempting to achieve a mouseover/mouseout effect in a powerpoint slide.

The idea is given three square shapes, change the line color of each independently on hover...

[image: shape line changes on hover]

*shape line changes on hover*

...then return it to its original state on mouseout. I know PP doesn't support mouseout, so I'm attempting to use [the mouseout hack consisting of another shape with a mouseout macro mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967762/1592764) -

[image: shape lines reset when mouse is over background shape]

*shape lines reset when mouse is over background shape*

I'm trying to use the following macros to achieve this. shapeHover() is triggered when the mouse is on a square. MouseOutHack() is supposed to be triggered when the mouse is on the background shape, but the lines are not resetting to their original color. Is there a problem with my macros? Both are in the same module.

```
Option Explicit

Public myShape As Shape ' Global reference to mouse over shape

Sub shapeHover(oShp As Shape)
  Set myShape = oShp
  With oShp
    ' Change the properties you need here
    oShp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End With
End Sub

Sub MouseOutHack()
  With oShp
    ' Reset the properties you need here
    oShp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think in `Sub MouseOutHack()` you may use `With myShape` instead of `With oShp`. `myShape` used to be set as the last shape modified with `Sub shapeHover(oShp As Shape)`. Also no need to use `oShp.Line.....` since you are using with. Only `.Line....` will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ahmed AU said ... use myShape in MouseOutHack and leverage the With statements if you're going to use them ... and then it'll work.

```
Option Explicit

Public myShape As Shape ' Global reference to mouse over shape

Sub shapeHover(oShp As Shape)
  Set myShape = oShp
  With oShp
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End With
End Sub

Sub MouseOutHack()
  With myShape
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  End With
End Sub
```